# Gitlab CI run job automatically on main branch and allow manual job for other branches

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

It is often handy to have job running on main branch, but allow for manual exectution on other branches. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [rules:if](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif):

```
my-job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
    - when: manual # otherwide run manually
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules

$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH is usually main branch

```
job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
    - when: manual
```